# Locking the interval of a chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, intervals

I need a little help:
I made a chart in that i have two lines and the second changes its values when clicking on the datagridview next to it. I gave the chartarea some options, like:

```
>         Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = Motor.mcrDrehzahl.Min - 100
>         Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Motor.mcrDrehzahl.Max + 100
>         Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0
>         Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = Motor.mcrLeistung.Max + 100
>         Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalAutoMode =DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount
>         Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount
```

But here comes the problem: When I click on the datagridview the second line changes as it should but sometimes the interval of x and/or y-axis is changing too. I want to do NOT allow that. So how can I lock the intervall after it was automaticly set the first time? I thought that is what intervallautomode does?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Interval` property, and set it to the desired value:

```
Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 123.45;
Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 678.90;
```

Also look at your button's click event handler, and make sure it's not telling the chart to recalculate it's min/max/interval...